# Can I use bitwise OR for Java Enums

Tags: java

Suppose you have an enum Direction

```
enum Direction{
    North,South,East West
}
```

Could I write a method that uses bitwise or's to compare multiple enums

```
public boolean canGoDirection(Direction dir){
     return dir | Direction.North;
}
```

where I would call the above method as

```
this.canGoDirection(Direction.South | Direction.North);
```

Comment: java enums are normal objects (w/ special serialization), that's all; no overloaded operators (ala C) in java - thus 'no'.

Comment: I don't exactly know the meaning of `canGoDirection(Direction dir)`, but if you want to do a check, shouldn't there be an & instead of | ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't use a bitwise or like that.  Try something more like this:

```
public boolean canGoDirection(Set<Direction> dirs){
     return dirs.contains(Direction.North);
}
```

called like this:

```
this.canGoDirection(EnumSet.of(Direction.South,Direction.North));
```

Comment: For small EnumSet's, it uses a long and a bit mask. ;)

Answer (score 9):

The functionality that you are looking for is implemented by EnumSet.

Your example can be boiled to:

```
final static EnumSet<Direction> ALLOWED_DIRECTIONS =
    EnumSet.of( Direction.North, Direction.South );

public boolean canGoDirection(Direction dir){
     return ALLOWED_DIRECTIONS.contains( dir );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but if you add a primitive (e.g. `int`) field to your enum, you can OR that `int` value.

However, the resulting value is of `int` (which can not be implicitly converted to `boolean`, much less back to `enum`).

Probably you would be better off using an [`EnumSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) instead. This is much more idiomatic to Java.

Comment: Indeed.  But of course, for this to make any sense, the OP would need to define his `enum` as something like `North(1),South(2),East(4),West(8)`.