# Java adding enums in a method

Tags: java, enums

I need to modify the 3rd method `mapDirectionToTrafficProfileDirection()` to display `Both`. `Direction` class is an enum class and just has `IN and OUT`.

```
public enum Direction {
IN,
OUT;
```

and  `TrafficProfileExtension` class also has enum for Direction `Egress, Ingress, Both;`

```
public class TrafficProfileExtension {
private TrafficProfile entity;
public static enum Direction {
    Egress, Ingress, Both;
}
```

I need to modify the 3rd method to dislay `Both` is there a way I can add it without changing/adding a new enum in Direction class?

```
private TrafficProfileExtension.Direction mapDirectionToTrafficProfileDirection (Direction direction){
    if (Direction.OUT.equals(direction)){
        return TrafficProfileExtension.Direction.Egress;
    }
    if (Direction.IN.equals(direction)){
        return TrafficProfileExtension.Direction.Ingress;
    }
    if (Direction. ??  .equals(direction)){
        return TrafficProfileExtension.Direction.Both;
    }
    return null;
}
    }
```

We have this method in our code and they were able to add the enum without changing the enum in `Direction` class. 
Example method below:

```
private  List<Direction> mapTrafficProfileDirection (TrafficProfileExtension.Direction direction)  throws  Exception  {

    List<Direction>  directionList = new ArrayList<Direction>();

    if (TrafficProfileExtension.Direction.Egress.equals(direction)){
        directionList.add(Direction.OUT);
        return directionList;
    }
    if (TrafficProfileExtension.Direction.Ingress.equals(direction)){
        directionList.add(Direction.IN);
        return directionList;
    }
    if (TrafficProfileExtension.Direction.Both.equals(direction)){
        directionList.add(Direction.OUT);
        directionList.add(Direction.IN);
        return directionList;

    }

    throw new Exception("Illegal direction passed through method " + direction.name());

}
```

Comment: So you want another enum value without creating a new enum value? I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: The Direction enum will never be both IN and OUT.  It can be IN, OUT, or null.

Comment: Well your direction right now obviously can't be "both" at the same time.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960167/can-i-use-bitwise-or-for-java-enums Other answer says Set<Direction> can be used instead of C++ style "or"

Comment: The problem is, that you didn't really tell what code you actually CAN modify. Can you modify the code having the direction as a variable? Can you modify the code setting that variable? Can you only modify the code checking it?

Comment: Are you sure that you have to add the third option? If `Direction` is only used by objects that require just IN and OUT, and you just want to convert it into the second type, then you translate what you have. I'd say the problem would be translating the reverse.

Answer (score 3):

You could call the method with `null` as a special case.

```
if (direction == null){
    return TrafficProfileExtension.Direction.Both;
}
```

That isn't a very clean solution though, as `null` would usually imply that there is "no direction".

---

So, it seems you are already using a list to map from `Direction` to `TrafficProfileExtension.Direction`, so why not use a list for mapping in the other direction too?

```
private TrafficProfileExtension.Direction mapDirectionToTrafficProfileDirection(List<Direction> directionList) {

    if(directionList.contains(Direction.IN) && directionList.contains(Direction.OUT)){
        return TrafficProfileExtension.Direction.Both;
    }
    if (directionList.contains(Direction.IN)){
        return TrafficProfileExtension.Direction.Ingress;
    }
    if (directionList.contains(Direction.OUT)){
        return TrafficProfileExtension.Direction.Egress;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in your `mapTrafficProfileDirection` method you are returning a `List<Direction>` to be able to map `TrafficProfileExtension.Direction` to `Direction`. Therefore you will have to accept a `List<Direction>` to do the inverse operation. You can overload it to accept just a single `Direction` but in that method you will not have to worry about the case of both directions.

```
mapDirectionToTrafficProfileDirection (List<Direction> direction)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to work with `Set<Direction>`:

```
public enum Direction {

    IN,
    OUT;

    public static final Set<Direction> BOTH = Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.allOf(Direction.class));
}

public static class TrafficProfileExtension {

    public static enum Direction {

        Egress, Ingress, Both;
    }

    private TrafficProfileExtension.Direction mapDirectionToTrafficProfileDirection(Set<Test.Direction> directions) {
        if (directions.containsAll(Test.Direction.BOTH)) {
            return Direction.Both;
        } else if (directions.contains(Test.Direction.IN)) {
            return Direction.Egress;
        } else if (directions.contains(Test.Direction.OUT)) {
            return Direction.Ingress;
        } else {
            // Neither!!! What do you want to do?
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an error when calling this method `The method mapDirectionToTrafficProfileDirection(Set<Direction>) in the type CosRetrieve is not applicable for the arguments (Direction)`  I am calling this method:  Direction direction = allocInfo.getDirection(); TrafficProfileExtension.Direction tpDirection = mapDirectionToTrafficProfileDirection(direction);

Comment: @Gio - I changed the signature to `Set<Test.Direction>`. Try `EnumSet.of` to make a `Set<Enum>`.